# Why aren't countries alphabetized on Configuration page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm running Magento 2.3 on Windows 10 with xampp.  I installed Magento by cloning the Github repo.

On the Configuration page, the countries are not showing in alphabetical order.  Do you have any idea why this happened, and how do I fix it?

[image]